# How to solve linear gradiant css issue in Safari Browser?

Tags: css, safari

I have used the css properties like

```css
background:linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68)100%),url(http://localhost/project/assets/uploads/bannerpages/74.jpeg);
```

But in safari browser linear gradiant property is not working at all.

Another property Of Height VH is also not working in safari .

```css
.hero-video-caption {
  height: 96vh!important;
}
```

What is possible solution for this two properties in safari browser

Comment: Which version of Safari are we talking about? Both features you mention have been in Safari since v6.1. Also, can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Even in Chrome the `background` property is set with an invalid value. Please make sure to use it properly.